# Flash message with html_safe from the controller in Rails 4 (safe version)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my controller I have the following code:

```rb
    format.html { redirect_to new_customer_url,
                notice: %Q[ A customer already exists with with this shopping id. Edit this customer #{view_context.link_to("here", edit_customer_url(@duplicate))}.
    ].html_safe
```

I would like to be able to include a link in a flash message, so (as you can see) I call html_safe to unescape the string.  However, it seems that as of Rails 4.1 this is now handled differently.  (See [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-core/z52zgDgUmbs) and [here](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2014/07/24/flash-access-changes-rails-4-1.html))

A solution to this has been provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887814/rails-4-link-in-flash-message-is-not-parsed-as-html?answertab=votes#tab-top). However, it only does so by moving the `html_safe` call to the view, having the effect of unescaping all flash messages.

I would prefer to be a bit more paranoid than that, is there any way to include the link in the flash message from the controller?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is one possible way to solve this problem. Add a before filter to your `ApplicationController` which will make `flash[:notice]` html safe only if `flash[:html_safe]` is set. Then you can control when and when not to make notices html safe completely from the controller.

```
before_filter -> { flash.now[:notice] = flash[:notice].html_safe if flash[:html_safe] && flash[:notice] }
```

Then your example could be modified to this:

```
format.html do
  redirect_to(
    new_customer_url,
    notice: %Q[ A customer already exists with with this shopping id. Edit this customer #{view_context.link_to("here", edit_customer_url(@duplicate))}.],
    flash: { html_safe: true }
  )
end
```

Comment: as of Rails 4.2 this does not work
in controller tried 
flash[:notice] = "soem string <br> more text".html_safe

Comment: @user1136228 I just tried this with Rails 4.2.1 and 4.2.5 and it definitely worked. Please check your code.

Comment: In controller
flash[:notice] = "some message with <br> and more"
flash[:html_safe] = true

and then I check for flash[:html_safe] presence in layout.

If mark notice as html_safe in controller this not works for me

Comment: `#html_safe` does not work for this use case in Rails 4.2.1. I just did `flash[:warning] = "<a href='#'>Click Me</a>'".html_safe` and it printed out the html as a string on the page.

Comment: @sixty4bit You are not approaching this correctly. You must use html_safe during the request subsequent to setting `flash[:warning]`. That is why I have done it in a before filter in my example, which definitely works with Rails 4.2.1. Take a closer look at how the example functions.

Comment: thanks @WizardofOgz, you're right. I did it the way it's actually explained in this answer it worked correctly. I still don't understand what the difference is between doing it in the controller action that handled the request vs. after the redirect in a callback, though.

Comment: @sixty4bit at the end of one request the data in the flash is serialized to a datastore (cookie, database, redis, memcached, etc.). Then it deserialized at the beginning of the next request. During this process of serialization and deserialization the html_safe info is not preserved (although it would be possible to implement that).

Comment: what's the difference in using `before_action` vs `before_filter` in this particular case?

Comment: @BobChip there is no difference. `before_action` has been renamed as `before_filter` in newer versions of Rails.

Comment: @WizardofOgz I think it's other way around. `before_filter` was older syntax, `before_action` is newer

Comment: @anwar Yes, you are correct! I wrote them backwards by mistake.