# Flash message from controller: its html-code is displayed as text

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my controller, as part of the `create` method, I have a flash message:

```
flash[:success] = "An email was sent to #{@user.email}. Please check your inbox. <br> If you find this email in your junk mail folder, please mark the email as 'Not Junk'.".html_safe
```

The `<br>` in the middle however is displayed as text instead of that it processes it as html code and continues the text on a new line. This despite the use of `html_safe` at the end. Does anyone know what could be causing this and what to do about it?

**Update:** I tried it in other controller flash messages also. Just added `<br>` and `html_safe` to see how it would display and each time it caused problems. While in view pages, it doesn't generate any problems.

As requested the code that displays the flash messages (but even if I reduce this to just `<%= message %>` the problem still persists):

```
<% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, class: "alert alert-#{message_type}" do -%>
  <%= message %>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
  <% end -%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What you have works fine for me in Rails 4.2.3 - which specific Rails 4 are you using? Maybe there was a bug concerning this functionality.

Comment: Also, just for giggles, can you show the view code where you're displaying this (although I can't think of any way to counteract the `.html_safe` in modern Rails)

Comment: I am also using Rails 4.2.3. I've added the view code to the OP.

Comment: Umm, that's the code for displaying your model errors, not flash messages.

Comment: Sorry, updated it with the correct code.

Comment: Ack, I messed up my testing, and @nextstep was right all along.

Comment: This should help I hope:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538891/flash-message-with-html-safe-from-the-controller-in-rails-4-safe-version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<%= message.html_safe %>`

This will silently put all notices straight into html, so you **don't** really want to do this. You can do this if, and only if you are 100% sure, that your app never ever puts any user content in notices, or your app will be vulnerable to js injection attack. Instead try:

[Flash message with html_safe from the controller in Rails 4 (safe version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538891/flash-message-with-html-safe-from-the-controller-in-rails-4-safe-version)

So yes, add `before_filter -> { flash.now[:success] = flash[:success].html_safe if flash[:html_safe] && flash[:success] }` to your ApplicationController, and than, any time you set html safe `flash[:success]` also set `flash[:html_safe]` to true, like

```
flash[:success] = "An email was sent to #{@user.email}. Please check your inbox. <br> If you find this email in your junk mail folder, please mark the email as 'Not Junk'.".html_safe
flash[:html_safe] = true
```

Edit: Yes, you can skip .html_safe at the end. You can make it more generic and remove unnecesary message like

```
before_filter -> {
  if flash[:html_safe]
    flash.delete(:html_safe)
    flash.each do |k, message| 
      flash[k] = message.try(:html_safe)
    end
  end
}
```

Comment: What could be the problem if you "put all notices straight into html"? With the safe version: does this mean I should add to `application.html.erb`: `before_filter -> { flash.now[:notice] = flash[:notice].html_safe if flash[:html_safe] && flash[:notice] }`? And that's it? But it then only works for notice flashes...? and I'm not sure how it uses `flash[:html_safe]`; do I need to add something about that in the controller's flash message?

Comment: Basically, it could lead to hard-to predict security issue. Rails escape html tags not for convenience, but to protect your users.

Comment: Thanks, it works for the success flash message. But it now displays 2 flash messages: it also displays a 2nd flash message with the text "true".

Comment: Also, I suppose I can leave out `html_safe` at the end of the line `flash[:success]`? (that doesn't seem to make a difference)  And since I also have other types of flash messages this applies to, is there a way to make it more generic instead of only to `success` flash messages?

Comment: Thanks, I think: a) the first line should be `before_filter -> {` and b) in the `flash.each` line there's a `do` missing. If I then run the code, I get an  error message `undefined method 'html_safe' for true:TrueClass` referring to the `flash[k]=` line.

Comment: If I change it to `k == 'html_safe'`, then it generates the following error: `undefined method 'except!' for #<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x007f1cdc1787e8>`.

Comment: Still a problem, I'm afraid. No more error messages, so that's good. However, there still is a 2nd bar for a second flash message. Although it doesn't contain any text, the bar for the "true" flash message is still there.

Comment: Fixt once more, but if its still not there I surrender, FlashHash is one crazy class xD

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully @nextstep reads this an undeletes his answer because he was spot on.

You need to do the `.html_safe` in the display of your flash message, not when you set them because in between those things the message will be serialized to the session and so will lose the `html_safe` flag.

I screwed up in my testing because I was setting and displaying the flash message in the same request (and so it hadn't been serialized/deserialized in between being set and displayed).

So, as @nextstep originally said (basically), change your view to:

```
<%= message.html_safe %>
```