# Adding a remote link to the flash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rails-flash

Hi so I'm working on a project and I want to be able to have a link in the flash that opens in a modal, so I need the link to be remote. So I have

```
flash[:link] = { text: "Click here",
                 location: new_post_path,
                 remote: true 
               }
```

but when the flash is loaded, it doesn't actually load as a remote link?

Any help fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have never even seen flash[:link] before and a search doesn't bring up anything on it - do you have a view helper that is working with that? Maybe the output needs to be sanitised as indicated in a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887814/rails-4-link-in-flash-message-is-not-parsed-as-html. If this isn't helpful then consider posting the view code related to this and the generated html

Comment: he just want to attach the link for alert/flash/notice.

Comment: @henners66 Since rails 5 I think it is you can use any custom key in the flash

Comment: @j-dexx - suspected it may be a rails 5 feature, however how does it convert the hash to a link? Do you need to create a view helper or a custom  flash helper, or is this just rails magic? Actually, thinking about it, I suspect he is just using link_to flash[:link]

Comment: @henners66 The bit that's a rails 5 feature is the ability to use any key for the flash.  It doesn't have anything for linking as far as I know so they'll have to use something like dkp's solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
flash[:link] = "#{view_context.link_to('Click here',new_post_path, remote: true)}".html_safe
```

You should render you flash message in view as follows:

```
<% flash.each do |_, value| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, value %>
<% end %>
```