# Link is not resolved as a link by the browser

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

Using this in rails to create a text with an inline link:

```
controller.ensure_logged_in t("Text", :sign_up_link => view_context.link_to(t("more text"), sign_up_path)).html_safe
```

renders this to the Dom:

```
<div class="flash-text">
"
  Text <a href="/de/signup"> more text</a>.
"
</div>
```

and in the browser to:

```
Text <a href="/de/signup">more text</a>.
```

The link is not resolved as a link by the browser, how could I fix this in the controller?

Comment: Can you reword your question?  I do not understand what you mean that the link is not resolved as a link in the browser.  I see the link the the HTML, so it seems to me it is resolved as a link by the browser.

Comment: Its displayed as this text "Text <a href="/de/signup">more text</a>." in the browser. Its not a link, where you can click on it:/

Comment: An `a` tag would be a like you could click on.  So I don't understand.

Comment: Yes but thats not happening, its really writing just the text of the a tag to the display but its not converting it to a link where you can click on it. Maybe there is some script going on, I will have to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, as it is a flash notification, I had to sanitize the message, see also here:

[rails-4-link-in-flash-message-is-not-parsed-as-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24887814/rails-4-link-in-flash-message-is-not-parsed-as-html?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)